# Is there a way to condense this code?

Tags: c#, enums

I have all these blocks of code that all work  but I want to condense them just to look better. Any ideas?

```
    public static AccountEnum Direct()
    {
        const AccountEnum direct = AccountEnum .DIRECT;
        return direct;
    }

    public static AccountEnum Partner()
    {
        const AccountEnum partner = AccountEnum .PARTNER;
        return partner;
    }

    public static AccountEnum Resold()
    {
        const AccountEnum resold = AccountEnum .RESOLD;
        return resold;
    }

    public static AccountEnum Referral()
    {
        const AccountEnum referral = AccountEnum .REFERRAL;
        return referral;
    }
```

Comment: Could be better in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: 1. Why do you have a function to access an enum value? 2. Why do you first make a constant instead of just returning the value directly? 3. Maybe this is a question for codereview.

Comment: I don't think I understand why you're not referencing the enums directly instead of the static wrapper?

Comment: @SonerGönül, thanks will use it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no point in using const here. You can just do this:

```
public static AccountEnum Direct()
{
    return AccountEnum.DIRECT;
}

public static AccountEnum Partner()
{
    return AccountEnum.PARTNER;
}

public static AccountEnum Resold()
{
    return AccountEnum .RESOLD;
}

public static AccountEnum Referral()
{
    return AccountEnum .REFERRAL;
}
```

Though I'm doubtful there's much point in having these methods at all.

Answer (score 14):

Just allow people to access the Enum directly. There's no reason to have the methods there at all.

Comment: The enum is probably already public, the compiler would moan about inconsistent accessibility otherwise, no?

Comment: I just enjoying with upvotes..